# How to use HOG (Histogram of Gradient) with K-mean clustering for clustering the Text images?

Tags: matlab, k-means, feature-extraction, hierarchical-clustering, text-classification

I have used this code of HOG (Histogram of gradient) for clustering the text-images. I have got the row vector 1x1440 .  How can i pass it into k mean clustering algorithm for clustering.

```
img = imread('1.jpg');
[featureVector,hogVisualization] = extractHOGFeatures(img);
```

Here, my k-mean clustering code: I cannot pass a complete feature vector as one feature(single value).

```
inputFeature = featorvector;
[cidx2,extra] = kmeans(inputFeature,2);
```

Here is image 1.jpg :
[image: First Alphabet of Urdu Language]

Comment: Please post a sample image, answering a question is always easier if we can run your code.

Comment: I have uploaded image. first alphabet of Urdu language.